# Are there terminal commands to manipulate the current terminal window position and behaviour?

Tags: xubuntu, window, xfce4-terminal

I like to keep a single terminal open and set to "Always On Visible Workspace" as well as filling the right half of the screen when visible (snapped?).

I can do this with keyboard shortcuts and with mouse clicks on the window decoration but want to write a script to do this quickly in one swoop. Does anyone know the appropriate (presumanly) X-window commands?

I'm on Xubuntu 18.04, Xfce 4.12 with xfwm4. I can't find the commands I'm looking for online so thought I'd ask here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can look into xdotool

Answer (score 0):

Both `wmctrl` and `xdotool` are command line tools that can act on an existing window. Appropriate commands to position the selected window, or alternatively, select the target window and position it, can be included in a script or bound to a hotkey.

For a fully automated solution, where any terminal window automatically is tiled to the right and appears on all workspaces, `devilspie` or `devilspie2` are perfectly suited. These are small daemons that can change defined windows automatically as they are created. As such, you could automatically have a terminal window tiled to the right *and* be visible on all workspaces. You could also undecorate the window automatically, i.e., remove border and title bar.